# Missing ImageTk module with pillow and python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've installed pillow on Ubuntu 14.04.  I'm using python 2.7 for this project. There is no ImageTk module, although the [pillow web site](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html) says there is.  python finds PIL all right, but when I try to import ImageTk, the PIL compatibility layer (or whatever I should call it) tries to import the ImageTk module from the PIL module, and it's not there.  Other modules like Image, ImageChops and so on, are there.

I need the ImageTk module so that I can use JPEGs with tkinter.  What do I need to do?  Alternatively, using pillow can I create PhotoImages from JPEGs in tkinter without the ImageTk module?  How?

I've copied a terminal session below in case I haven't explained myself well.  Thanks for any assistance.

```
$ pip show pillow
---
Name: Pillow
Version: 2.3.0
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
saul@Banach:~ 
$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from PIL import ImageTk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name ImageTk
>>> import ImageTk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat/ImageTk.py", line 1 in <module>
from PIL.ImageTk import *
ImportError: No module named ImageTk
>>> quit()
saul@Banach:~ 
$ cat /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat/ImageTk.py
from PIL.ImageTk import *
saul@Banach:~ 
$ ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk*
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk*: No such file or directory
```